# Git Branch newbie - How to reverse?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-revert

Not sure if this is a proper way to work with branches.

- I had this application on structure A.
- I created a branch Z while I was on that structure A (but I kept my self on the master branch working).
- While working (on the master branch), I changed that structure and I end up messing the all thing. :)
- I've never commit nor added those new files to the rep.

Request:

- I need to revert to the structure existing on the last commit. Revert All Uncommitted changes and also remove new files and folders that may have been added.

**How can this be done?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you created a separate branch that got messed up, all you need to do is switch back to the one you were on before: `git checkout A` (assuming `A` is the name of the branch you were on... or maybe it's `master`).

You can delete the bad branch later, if you want, with `git branch -d <branchname>` and maybe throw in a `-f` too, if there are unmerged commits.

**Edit:** If your repository contains lots of bad changes you want to remove, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD` to undo them. If there are new files (not tracked by git), `git clean -fd` will remove them all. Obviously, use with discretion as they will not be recoverable by git.

Comment: @Dan: When I created the new branch, I believe, I was not switched to that branch automatically. After creating the branch, I still was working on my master branch I suppose. It seems that it has just take a snapshot. So, my master branch is messed up. I want to apply the structure that is on my other branch, into the master branch. Btw, should we avoid working directly on our master branch ?

Comment: @MEM - are there bad commits on master? If not, then while on master, `git reset --hard` will undo any uncommitted changes. If you have committed bad commits, use `git revert <badcommit>` to undo them. Once master is rewinded back to a "good" state, you can `git merge A` while on master which hopefully fixes things. If you don't know where the bad commit was, look into git bisect - very cool.

Comment: @Dan  - I've done git reset --hard - But I do see some files that were created (and not committed) after the branch creation. Perhaps I should do something else ?

Comment: @MEM - Do you need these files? If they were never in git, and they're not needed, just delete them from your file system. We may not be on the same page about the state of your repository. Maybe update your post with some output from git status/branch/etc.

Comment: Well, this question is dead I believe. :( I end up solving this by using some Netbeans option: "Revert All Uncommited changes in working tree and index" and I've also click on: "Remove also new files and folders". With this, I got it right.  But don't know, if this corresponds to a git command. When I did git reset --hard no files nor folders where changed. When I choose those options, those files as folders had been gone as well. So Netbeans optiosn ARE NOT = to, git reset --hard. I still don't know how to revert. I can give the status but I believe it's of no use on this state. So, nvm.

Comment: @MEM I just tried `git clean -fd` and that will remove all untracked files. I don't know if netbeans uses that command or does it manually, but for future reference, there ya go.

Comment: Nice! Yes, perhaps Netbeans uses that. Can't be sure. By untracked files you mean, not committed or not added files ? - Btw, please edit your question accordingly otherwise it will not make sense to others.

Comment: @MEM - Yes, files that are not in git, which include new ones not yet committed, as well as any in your .gitignore file. I will add this to my answer, and you may want to edit the question to use some updated terminology so that other users with similar situations might find it.

Answer (score 6):

> I need to reverse to structure A "snapshot" on branch Z

```
$ git checkout A
$ git branch -d Z
$ git branch Z
$ git reset --hard HEAD~3
$ git checkout Z
```

In English:

Delete your "Z" branch and re-make it from the current state of "A".

Reset your A branch back three commits. That's an EXAMPLE--three is probably not the right depth back in your history to reset to. Change that number to be the right number (and use `git log` to figure that out the number of commits back that your branches diverged).

Switch to your Z branch and confirm that your changes formerly in "A" are now in "Z".

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. Indeed I had a bad question. Still, if you don't mind, please don't delete your answer because it sure is useful.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you only created the branch with:

```
git branch Z
```

when you in fact wanted to create it and also switch to it. You can create a branch and switch to it by using the -b flag to git checkout, like this:

```
git checkout -b Z
```

What you need to do now is to undo the changes that you have committed to your master branch. This will undo the commit and make the index look just like before you made the commit:

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Then switch to Z and commit the changes from the index (already staged):

```
git checkout Z
git commit -m "blah blah"
```

Hope this helps.

Oh and yes avoid working directly on master, unless it's a simple bug fix.

---

> Please keep your answer because it
>   contains important notions that I must
>   understand. That didn't work. What I
>   need is to: grab branch Z and place it
>   as a master - is this possible ?

Of course it is. You can do this in a lot of different ways. If there is only one commit you could merge the Z branch into master to get that commit into master. But I'm assuming that you dont want the commit on the Z branch at all. Then you can do the same but switch branches, e.g.:

```
git checkout Z
git reset --soft HEAD^
git checkout master
git commit -m "blah blah"
```

Comment: Please keep your answer because it contains important notions that I must understand. That didn't work. What I need is to: grab branch Z and place it as a master - is this possible ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Magnus. Sorry for all this mess. :( I end up realising that I didn't know what I was looking for in git jargon. Sorry again.